Snap's equivalent to FlatPak's list --app command
The command
flatpak list --app

will only list installed applications,  not shared / platform components / libraries like FreeDesktop, Gtk, bare, core22 etc.
Is there an equivalent for Snap? Gandered at (to no avail):
snap list --help


Whoever suggested the other question, that also doesn't answer mine, it just filters out snaps that are authored by Canonical, however those might be apps (eg. Chromium). Please carefully read the question again

The answers maybe insufficient, but that doesn't change the fact that the questions are asking for the same thing.

I have found out that the answer is that currently no, snap is not capable of listing only installed apps, and will list all snaps which includes those installed as dependencies, base snaps, platform components, etc.
The accepted answer to the question that was incorrectly suggested as a duplicate, https://askubuntu.com/a/1434373/782055, suggests running
ls -l /snap/bin
ls -l /var/lib/snapd/snaps

That doesn't provide an answer as the first command only lists binaries (but some snaps don't install any), and the second one lists all snaps including ones that aren't apps.
